# Terry Cain Razer Drivers fail to install due to python3-setproctitle being uninstallable

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel, python3, additional-drivers

I am attempting to install 3rd party open source razor drivers from: https://github.com/terrycain/razer-drivers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:terrz/razerutils
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-razer razer-kernel-modules-dkms razer-daemon razer-doc
```

However the last command fails with the error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    razer-daemon : Depends: python3-setproctitle but it is not installable
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have attempted to install the dependency manually via `pip` with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install setproctitle
```

The installation is fine, I am testing it like so:

```
from setproctitle import setproctitle
from os import getpid, system
setproctitle('this-is-a-test')
system("ps -o cmd= {}".format(getpid())
```

`python3 test.py`

it prints

> this-is-a-test

However the command `sudo apt install python3-razer razer-kernel-modules-dkms razer-daemon razer-doc`

still fails with the same error message.

How might I get around this issue?

Comment: Please don't use ``` for fenced code blocks; this isn't GitHub.

Comment: The package is available in 16.04, and 16.10: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-setproctitle. Make sure you use the correct distro.

Comment: The documentation for the driver states that the PPA supports `14.04`. Have I made an error when installing `setproctitle`?

Comment: The PPA does provide packages for 14.04, but the package `python3-setproctitle` is not in 14.04's repositories. You may want to contact the maintainer of the PPA and ask about it.